# Calling 'this' inside of firebase once function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vue-component

So I am creating a Vuejs application and I am trying to fetch firebase data on component mount. That is working, but I try to write the value into a vuejs data property. For this I would only call `this.property = snapshot.val();` inside the firebase function (see code below) but that is not working: `this is undefined`

So my code just is:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imageList: "No images!"
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        ...
      };

      firebase.initializeApp(config);

      var database = firebase.database();
      var ref = database.ref("images").orderByChild("date");


    firebase.database().ref("images/").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        this.imageList= snapshot.val();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I tried calling `this.imageList= snapshot.val();` outside of the function with a variable to store the value, and 'this' wasn't undefined anymore, but the data wasn't there because the request hasn't finished yet.

So basically I want to get the snapshot.val(); into this.imageList!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use es6 arrow function syntax to solve the issue.

```
firebase.database().ref("images/").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    this.imageList= snapshot.val();
});
```

or bind this to the context of the function.

```
var that = this;
```

Comment: I'll try that out! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use an arrow function, a closure, or `bind`.

```
firebase.database().ref("images/").once('value').then(snapshot => {
  this.imageList= snapshot.val();
});
```

See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind` as well.

```
firebase.database().ref('images/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  this.imageList = snapshot.val()
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: I tried binding this way, but it wasn't working, but maybe I missed something, thanks!